# hibernate hql like criteria on date type field

Tags: hibernate, date, hql, hql-like

I have a project based on hibernate, my database is SQL Server. I have a need to search on a table (`SalesRepsMaster`) irrespective of any field on `like` criteria. There is one date field, so on `like` criteria this fails, I checked in sql query that works fine. I can not use any SQL, I have to use proper HQL, can anyone please tell me the HQL of bellow mentioned SQL? or HQL that corresponds to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),lastLoginDate,102)`?

```sql
Select  *  From SalesRepsMaster WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),lastLoginDate,102) like '%2013%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use built.in function:

```
cast(lastLoginDate as string) like '%2013%'
```

or (better, IMO)

```
year(lastLoginDate) = 2013
```

Comment: last one I can not use since like can be '%2013-08', better was first one but I can not convert date to string at runtime, can you please tell me anyway that hibernate can convert date to string?

Comment: You can't use HQL for this problem (`cast()` probably don't use 102 format)); use native query or `Criteria` with `Restrictions.sqlRestriction()`